# Column-wise sampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        A=[0, 0, 0.5, 0.6],
        B=[0, 0.7, 0.1, 0],
        C=[1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4],
    )
)
```

I want a sampling method that returns an array/list like:

```py
['C', 'B', 'C', 'A']
```

with the following property:

- At each element of the array, the probability of this element being `A`, `B` or `C` is proportional to the value of the columns `A`, `B` and `C` in that row number, respectively.

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try generate a random array, then compare to the cumulative distribution along the rows, and finally use `idxmax`:

```
s = np.random.rand(len(df))
df.cumsum(1).gt(s[:,None]).idxmax(1)
```

Test the approach:

```
counts = 0

for _ in range(1000):
    s = np.random.rand(len(df))
    sample = df.cumsum(1).gt(s[:,None]).idxmax(1)
    counts = pd.crosstab(sample.index, sample).add(counts, fill_value=0)
```

Output (close to original dataframe):

```
col_0      A      B     C
row_0                    
0        0.0    0.0  1000
1        0.0  688.0   312
2      514.0   96.0   390
3      601.0    0.0   399
```

Comment: Does this assume that the weights sum 1 for each row?

Comment: @DavidMasip yes it does.